# Azure Virtual network gateway

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

We have successfully setup the VPN Tunnel from our On-premise DC to Azue Vnet (Let say VNet1) and now we are trying to access another VNet (Let say VNet2) which is connected to VNet1 via peering but we are unable to access VNet2 from our On-premise N/w. Please let me know if you have any solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable "Allow transit" when within create VNet peering.

Please see following site:
Azure Virtual Networks - Transit Routing - Between IPsec & VNet Peering

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35830.azure-virtual-networks-transit-routing-between-ipsec-vnet-peering.aspx

VNet Peering and Gateway Transit with S2S VPN

http://www.deployazure.com/network/virtual-network/vnet-peering-and-gateway-transit-with-s2s-vpn/